# Can a participle stand alone in a German sentence

Tags: adjective, sentence-structure

Case: ‘Es gibt eine semantische Beziehung zwischen den Worten »Katze« und »Tier«.’

I would like talk about the sentence above, but I’m confused if I should use the actual noun or not?

> Das Erste ist ein untergeordnetes Semem des Zweiten.

Is it possible to rewrite this sentence like below?

> Das Erste ist untergeordnete des Zweiten

Answer (score 3):

The first possibility is an ellipsis (probably what you tried to do):

> Das erste [Semem] ist ein untergeordnetes des zweiten.

A slightly better version is:

> Das erste [Semem] ist dem zweiten untergeordnet.

To construct this, you need to know the grammatical case implied by the participle and, if needed, the corresponding preposition. As for *untergeordnet*, you need a dative object without a preposition.

For the sake of completeness: You could also substantiate the participle:

> Das erste [Semem] ist (ein) **U**ntergeordnetes des zweiten.

This sounds rather scholary; a literal translation would be "The first sememe is a subordinate element of the second" rather than "The first sememe is subordinate to the second". In a very abstract and/or mathematical context, this might be acceptable, but otherwise you should avoid such expressions.

Comment: @CEIrim, i was trying imply with _das erste_ to _the first one_, with _des zweiten_ to _of the second one_ i.e. the first one is the subordinate of the second one.